# Spring: How to POST Request into a ManyToMany Relation

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have two entities, `Meal` and `Mealplan` in a @ManyToMany Relation. Each Mealplan consists  of five Meal objects.

**Meal:**

```
@Entity
public class Meal {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private BigDecimal price;
    private String type;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "mealsPerWeek")
    private List<Mealplan> mealplan;
}
```

**Mealplan:**

```
public class Mealplan {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private int calendarweek;

    @ManyToMany
    private List<Meal> mealsPerWeek;
```

The JSON of for example `/mealplan/1` looks like this:

```
{
id: 1,
calendarweek: 10,
mealsPerWeek: [
   {
   id: 4,
   name: "Linsensuppe",
   price: 23.5,
   art: "vegan"
   },
   {
   id: 3,
   name: "Salat",
   price: 3,
   art: "vegetarisch"
   },
```

Now I want to create a (custom?) method to add a Meal into a Mealplan. What is the best way to do it? I was thinking about a custom Method in my Repository like this:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/mealplan")
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", allowedHeaders = "*")
public class MealplanController {

    @PostMapping
    public void addMealToMealplan(@RequestBody Meal meal) {
        mealplanRepository.addMealToMealplan(essen);
    }
```

But how can I add this custom method into the repository? How does a performant method for this look like?

```
@Repository
public interface MealplanRepository extends JpaRepository<Mealplan, Integer> {

 void addMealToMealplan(Meal meal);
}
```

Does not work for example plus I can not declare a Method in a Interface. Do I need a new Class for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with something like this :

For sure create MealRepository jpa interface

```
@Repository
public interface MealRepository extends JpaRepository<Meal, Integer> {
}
```

then preferably create MealPlanService to handle any operations on objects ( not to do actual work in controller), injecting both repositories. And whenever we are adding new meal we persist it first , and then add to colleciton of meals on mealplan object. Transactional to automatically update mealplans ( you can manually invoke save on mealplan )

```
@Service
public class MealPlanService{
    private MealRepository  _mealRepository;
    private MealPlanRepository _mealPlanRepository;

    @Autowire
    MealPlanService(MealRepository mealRepository,MealPlanRepository mealPlanRepository)
      _mealRepository = mealRepository
      _mealPlanRepository = mealPlanRepository
    }

    @Transactional
    public Mealplan addMealToMealplan(int mealPlanId, Meal meal) throws MealNotFoundException{
          Mealplan mealplan = _mealPlanRepository.findById(mealPlanId).orElseThrow(MealNotFoundException::new)
          meal = _mealRepository.save(meal); 
          mealplan.getMealsPerWeek().add(meal)
          return mealplan;
    }
}
```

And in Controller  autowire service and execute. Good stuff about it you can additionally secure and gracefully catch if somebody tries to alter not existing mealplan , or not his ( with some extra logic in service)

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/mealplan")
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", allowedHeaders = "*")
public class MealplanController {
    private MealPlanService _mealPlanService;

    @Autowire
    MealplanController (MealPlanService mealPlanService){
            _mealPlanService = mealPlanService;
    }

    @PostMapping(path = "/{mealPlanId}/add")
    public ResponseEntity<MealPlan> addMealToMealplan(@PathVariable int mealPlanId , @RequestBody Meal meal) {
            try{
                 return ResponseEntity.ok(_mealPlanService.addMealToMealplan(meal));
            catch (MealNotFoundException e){
                 //do some other logic, return error , log it or smth
                 ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
            }
    }
```

POST request on `/mealplan/1/add` with body of new meal (where 1 is your `mealPlanId` to which meal should be added ).

Controller will call service service which will try to first find mealplan based on passed id  `_mealPlanRepository.findById(mealPlanId)`

This will return Optional and we chain operation of geting value by calling `_mealPlanRepository.findById(mealPlanId).orElseThrow(MealNotFoundException::new)`

On found entity we then add our new meal ( it will be persisted due to Transactional , but you can invoke `_mealPlanRepository.save()` on it instead of

If everything is done corectly, service retus updated entity, and controller then returns Response entity with updated mealplan

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, I will for sure test it. I already have a MealRepository, but not a Service in general. ATM I only have a Controller and a Repository. How does the Method in the Service gets executed in the Controller?

Comment: Updated my answer with edit in controller as well, might be some typos or smth as was typing this without any IDE checks :)

Comment: Thanks for your update. Now I get the proposal of Services. But I have a problem: I can not write `Mealplan mealplan = mealplanRepository.findById(id)` because it would return a List or Optional<Meaplan>. And if I change it, I can not the getMealsPerWeek Method. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Hence the  ```_mealPlanRepository.findById(mealPlanId).orElseThrow(MealNotFoundException::new)``` - it's a chained operation . findByI() will return Optional<MealPlan>. orElseThrow will ge the instance or throws exception if it's empty   . See more of optional ( I do recomend it :)  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElseThrow-java.util.function.Supplier-

Comment: Added more updates info to original answer..sorry probably added way to many things at once :)